# i am using Misc Destination to forward incoming calls to an external destination ( outside my asterisk )

Tags: asterisk

i created a "Misc Destination" on Freepbx with a target external number and than added an inbound route that will forward all incoming calls to that DID to the number defined in the "Misc Destination"

i have some questions :
1.where is the configuration file of "Misc Destination" on the asterisk 
2.where is the configuration  file with all the inbound routes on the asterisk
3.if i get an incoming call to my asterisk and i use this method to forward the call to another external number ( not in my asterisk ) who will be charged ( $$ ) on that call???

please assist me i am new on asterisk

Answer (score 0):

1. /etc/asterisk.extensions_additional.conf
2. same as #1
3. The call will pay to call you, you will pay to call the next leg (the external number)